# How to perform partial string search in AWS Cloud Search using GET API request

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to search whole string as well as partial string in AWS Cloud Search API,

I have data available like below format,

```
[
{
  'name' : 'John',
  'specialities' : [
     'ios',
     'swift',
     'react native'
  ]
}, 
{
  'name' : 'Karl',
  'specialities' : [
     'ios developer',
  ]
}, 
{
  'name' : 'Maria',
  'specialities' : [
     'android developer',
  ]
}
]
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is if i fire query to search 'ios developer', then it should return Karl, John, Maria all three records.

Because as per my requirement Karl has fully matched string, that I am getting, but John has 'ios' and Maria has 'developer' word which I want to match.

As per AWS documentation they allows exact match of words and that's why I am not getting desired result.

I have referred below and related docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-phrases

Answer (score 0):

From those docs, what you're looking for is `|`

> |—include documents that contain the term in the search results, even
>   if they don't contain the other terms. The | operator only applies to
>   individual terms. For example, to include documents that contain
>   either of two terms, specify: term1 |term2. Searching for
>   search?q=star wars |trek includes documents that contain both star and
>   wars, or the term trek.

e.g. `ios |developer`

If you want to limit the results to only the `specialities` field you can still use this simple parser with options:

e.g. `q='ios |developer'&q.options={fields: ['specialities']}.`

Note that you are required to url encode this string. Most languages have a solution to do this, or you can do it using an online tool like: https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: Well this will not work as my desired values are inside string array which is `specialities`, and by default cloud search will search in texts only fields, but for me I have to mention field name. like `search?q.parser=structured&q=(and+specialities: 'ios developer')`

Comment: See my edit- I think you can still do this using the simple search.